# How Do I Install a Jar?

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I was reading some documentation for `db2jcc4.jar` when something caught my attention in the following (emphasis added):

> The following command will retrieve the JCC driver version if executed from the command line:
>
> `java com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Jcc -version`
>
> Or for drivers that are **not yet installed**:
>
> `java -cp ./db2jcc.jar com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Jcc -version`

All I have is the `db2jcc4.jar` file - it didn't come with an installer or anything. I can run the second command and it works fine, but the first gives me this stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Jcc
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Jcc
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:665)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:644)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:627)
Could not find the main class: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Jcc.  Program will exit.
```

This tells me that the jar is **not yet installed**. In all the time I've worked with Java, I've never heard of installing a jar. How can I make it so that the first command works instead of having this issue and printing a stack trace? How can I **install a jar**?

It looks to me like the second command includes a flag, `-cp`, which modifies the classpath. I'm guessing that means that all I need to do is move my jar file into a specific directory. I tried putting it in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.33.x86_64/jre/lib` but that didn't make it so the second command would work. I'm stumped and would appreciate any suggestions for where exactly I need to move this jar for it to be considered **installed**.

Comment: I don't recommend installing the jar as a JRE extension, it will couple your applications to the JRE install. Why not use the second option as part of a shell script?

Comment: @ChristianWilkie: My question was more about what the documentation meant by "install" than how to actually run this specific command. I was getting some really bizarre behavior with some classes within the jar, where classes were sometimes being found and other times just not being found (despite classloader logs showing it had clearly been loaded). I was just reading over the full documentation when it occurred to me that, by their definition, I hadn't "installed" the jar, so I wanted to know how I could satisfy that. Once I did, the issues went away and I accepted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as "installing" a jar. To be used by a Java application, jars have to be accessible in the classpath. Take a look at this link:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Comment: Your link has this comment - (Classes that are part of the JRE, JDK platform, and extensions should be defined through other means, such as the bootstrap class path or the extensions directory.) - How would I go about adding the jar through that?

Comment: You shouldn´t do it, but in case it was necessary: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/install.html

Comment: Thank you - that looks like it should help a lot.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare - which part of **"You shouldn´t do it"** do you not not understand?  :-)

Comment: @StephenC: After placing the jar in the ext directory, it worked perfectly. Whether I should do it or not is irrelevant - it got the job done.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare - how can you say that if you don't understand why it is a bad idea?  For example, suppose I told you the solution to users forgetting their passwords was to set all passwords to "secret".  It gets the job done ... but there is more to it than that.

Comment: @StephenC: I understand why it would be a bad idea if this JVM installation were going to exist for a long time and be used for other things, but it won't. This is a server VM running a single application. I spin up and throw out the VM elastically to scale with demand. I'm not concerned about its ability to run other applications or about updating Java (part of my spin up script involves getting the latest copy of Java, then it inserts this jar.)

Answer (score 1):

> It looks to me like the second command includes a flag, -cp, which modifies the classpath. I'm guessing that means that all I need to do is move my jar file into a specific directory.

I would say that you need to explicitly include the jar file itself on the classpath. Personally, I generally do not attempt to "install" a jar as you describe, but rather create some sort of script or executable jar file that will facilitate the establishment of the correct classpath.

EDIT: In the context of deploying code to an application server, then "installing" the jar would make sense--typically there's a shared lib folder available on an application server where you can simply drop the jar and the code will become available to all the applications running on the server--this can become a bit of a management headache, however and I often will prefer to have a completely self-contained deployment over sharing jar files between applications--YMMV, however.

Answer (score 0):

By installing the java jar they meant that the jar is available to your program (physically present and found in your class path). If the Path to the jar was not setup then you have to options:
+ copy the jar file to your existing path
+ include the jar file in the command line

```
java -cp <path_to>/db2jcc.jar com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Jcc -version
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that "Installing a JAR" is a poorly chosen terminology that likely means placing the jar on the JVM classpath" - i.e. in order to make it available to an application. The recommended ways of doing so vary depending on the Java platform (whether it is a server platform or a client side platform).

For example, on a Java EE server, you could package the jar file within the application, or define it as a shared library, and attach it to the server's classloader or the application's classloader to make it available to that application. Third party applications, such as various IBM products, will come with their own instructions as to how to 'install' a db2jcc4 driver.

Answer (score 0):

You commented thus:

> Your link has this comment - (Classes that are part of the JRE, JDK platform, and extensions should be defined through other means, such as the bootstrap class path or the extensions directory.) - How would I go about adding the jar through that?

That is a bad idea, for (at least) the following reasons:

- Putting stuff into the extensions directory is going to potentially affect every Java application that you execute.  Not just the application that you are trying to "install".  In some cases, this may to lead to unexpected breakages due to conflicting versions, etcetera.
- When you update the Java installation, the standard installer, RPM or whatever is going to create a new installation tree.  But it won't copy anything from the existing installation.  So a Java update is likely to break any application that depends on stuff in "extensions".
- If you try to solve the above problems by "embedding" a Java installation, you risk losing track of where your Java installations are.  This makes applying Java security patches problematic.  And of course, embedded JREs take up a lot of disc space ... at ~100Mb a time.

Comment: This is a server VM running a single application. I spin up and throw out the VM elasticaly to scale with demand. I'm not concerned about its ability to run other applications or about updating Java (part of my spin up script involves getting the latest copy of Java, then it inserts this jar.)